# Execute function after zoom highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to execute a function after zoom on a chart in Highcharts ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the **afterSetExtremes** event:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function(event){
                if (this.getExtremes().dataMin < event.min)
                    alert("Zoomed in!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RcdfW/