# Disable marker in highchart on 6m, 1y zoom level

Tags: highcharts

How do I disable markers at a certain zoom level.
Specifically I would not like to display markers when zooming at 6m, 1yr and All

```
plnkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gReLtSy0WhA49q0NinpD?p=preview
```

Comment: Perhaps you could trigger an event when zoomed in that updates the marker properties for that series. Here's a question I found that talks about zoom events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240510/execute-function-after-zoom-highcharts

Comment: Hi, I think that you can use afterSetExtremes event callback function and inside it check what button was clicked. You can remove markers from your series using Series.update() method. Here you can see simple example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/e2vhw3ez/1/